# Cakephp 3.6 Paginator->sortDir() shows only "asc"

Tags: cakephp

I have this paginator situation:

```
$this->Paginator->options([
    'url' => [
        'controller' => $paginatorUrl,
        'cat_id' => $catValue,
        'reg_id' => $locValue,
        'priceMin' => $priceValueMin,
        'priceMax' => $priceValueMax,
        'ref' => $ref,
        'sort' => $sort,
        'direction' => $direction
    ]
]);
$this->Paginator->templates([
    'sort'      => '<a href="{{url}}" class="btn-sort-order button-1 btn-hover-1 pull-right">{{text}}<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>',
    'sortAsc'   => '<a href="{{url}}" class="btn-sort-order button-1 btn-hover-1 pull-right">{{text}}<span class="fa fa-angle-up"></span></a>',
]);
```

And a simple link like this:

```
<?=$this->Paginator->sort(
                          'obj_preis',
                          __('Preis sortieren'),
                          ['escape' => false]
                        );?>
```

But I always get a link displayed which wants to sort in direction=desc.
Whatever I try, it will be always direction=desc.

Any ideas? Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your 'field' argument matches the casing of your database column. If the argument and sort column vary in casing CakePHP cannot match them together and will not reverse the sort direction.

Comment: Thank you Mark! This was absolutely the right answer! I had indeed a missmatching in field names!